# Invalid Hook in react js

Tags: reactjs

The Error:
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
   See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

The code: chatCreate.js (react.js)

```
import { useRef } from 'react';
import {Container, Form} from 'react-bootstrap';

export default function chatcreate() {
    var idref = useRef

    return (
        <Container>
            <Form>
                <Form.Group>
                    <Form.Label>Enter your id</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control type='text' ref={idref} required />
                </Form.Group>
            </Form>
            
        </Container>
        
    )
    

}
```

Comment: It should be `useRef()`

Answer (score 1):

It should work like this:

```
import { useRef } from 'react';
import { Container, Form } from 'react-bootstrap';

export default function chatcreate() {
    const idRef = useRef();

    return (
        <Container>
            <Form>
                <Form.Group>
                    <Form.Label>Enter your id</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control type='text' ref={idRef} required />
                </Form.Group>
            </Form>
        </Container>  
    );
}
```

Comment: Can you explain more about what this does?  Why `const` instead of `var`?  Why `useRef()` instead of `useRef`?   Why add semi-colons?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller `const` is better to use in cases like these since it's scope isolated. This means that `idRef` will exists only in the `chatcreate` function and nowhere else. `useRef` is a hook and hooks are like functions, they need to be called, otherwise you are just assigning the function to the variable without using it. As for the semi-colons - they're not necessary but in my opinion, they make the code easier to read.